# AS2 optimized code

Tags: optimization, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am trying to implement a logging mechanism in my code. I have read in some forums that in AS2, string concatenation does not happen at compile time, instead it happens at runtime.

I wanted to know which of the following codes is more optimal:

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    var strToReplace:String = "{" + i + "}";
}
```

or,

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    var strToReplace:String = "{%s}".split("%s").join(String(i));
}
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated as I am a newbie as far as AS2 is concerned. Thank you.

Comment: Honestly, if you care about these kinds of optimizations, you should be using AS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way to test :

```
var n:Number = 100000;

var beforeTime:Number = getTimer();

for (var i:Number = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
  var strToReplace:String = "{" + i + "}";
}

var betweenTime:Number = getTimer();
trace("between : " + (betweenTime - beforeTime));

for (var i:Number = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
  var strToReplace:String = "{%s}".split("%s").join(String(i));
}

var afterTime:Number = getTimer();
trace("after : " + (afterTime - betweenTime));
```

What I get in the traces :

- between : 269
- after : 866

The first way is 3 times faster : split and join methods have to search inside your string to execute.

If your string is bigger, the difference is even bigger : the first methode duration doesn't change... The second one takes even more time.
You should try.